# How do I refactor getter and setter methods using retain release?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to implement a gitHub project called [OCCCalendarView](https://github.com/ocrickard/OCCalendar) but it appears that the project was written pre-arc and I want to know how to refactor this method so that I can use it with iOS 7 & 8. How do I get rid of the retain & releases?

```
- (void)setStartDate:(NSDate *)sDate 
{
    if(startDate)
    {
        [startDate = release];
        startDate = nil;
    }
    startDate = [sDate retain];
    [calView setStartDate:startDate];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to refactor. Use the file as is and mark that one .m file as not using ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saying: The code that you copied is unsafe. If you call myObject.date = myDate; myObject.date = myDate; twice, things will go wrong. But never mind, the correct code is

```
- (void)setStartDate:(NSDate *)sDate 
{
    startDate = sDate;
    calView.startDate = startDate;
}
```

You could instead write

```
- (void)setStartDate:(NSDate *)sDate 
{
    if (startDate != sDate)
    {
        startDate = sDate;
        calView.startDate = startDate;
    }
}
```

It looks like the code you copied uses an instance variable named "startDate". That's quite a bad practice. You should change it to _startDate; you might have to change a @synthesize statement. And then the code is

```
- (void)setStartDate:(NSDate *)sDate 
{
    if (_startDate != sDate)
    {
        _startDate = sDate;
        calView.startDate = _startDate;
    }
}
```

The "if" is useful if the calView does the same thing and tries to change your startDate when its startDate is changed.

Comment: Thanks gnasher, exactly what I needed. I know I could have just marked the file as not using ARC but I wanted to avoid doing that for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Properties defined as `retain` become `strong`. Properties for objects defined as `assign`, become `weak`. After that, get rid of any explicit call to `retain`, `release`, or `autorelease`. Additionally, `dealloc` should no longer call `super`.